# Data not appearing in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying everything I could but nothing seems to work. I am trying to pass firebase user information from one view controller to another, but it never appears.

It starts from a table view 
The table view is populated with users that are being pulled from my firebase database. When the user selects a cell the following code gets executed:
I reference function "showProfileControllerForUser" as a way to transport the data of the cell that was selected

```
var mainProfile: userProfileNavigator?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user1 = self.users[indexPath.row]
self.mainProfile?.showProfileControllerForUser(user3: user1)

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc: UINavigationController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavProfile") as!  UINavigationController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In "userProfileNavigator" is where the function that was used before is. The function passes the information that was collected and passes that to the final destination.

```
 func showProfileControllerForUser(user3: User){
    mainProfile?.user2 = user3
}
```

Finally, "mainProfile" is where I want the data to be passed to.

```
var user2: User?{
    didSet{
       navigationItem.title = user2?.name
    }
```

I could imagine this being very confusing, I can provide anymore information or clarity if needed

attempted to setup table as such:

```
var mainProfile: mainProfile?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user1 = self.users[indexPath.row]
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainProfile")
    self.mainProfile?.user2 = user1
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the ViewController in which the information is being passed as such:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class mainProfile: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("lets see if this is the new user", user2.name as Any)


}
 var user2 = User()

}
```

but it still comes up as "nil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question right, then you have two `ViewControllers`. One which contain `UITableView`, and another is `ShowProfileControllerForUser`.

In `ViewController` which contain `UITableView`, code this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let user1 = self.users[indexPath.row]    
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc: UINavigationController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavProfile") as!  UINavigationController
        vc.user3 = user1
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Also, I am not sure if you're presenting the right `ViewController`.

In your `ShowProfileControllerForUser.swift`,

```
var user3 = User // declare a variable with proper type.
```

Now in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      showProfileControllerForUser(user3)
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
var mainProfile: mainProfile?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user1 = self.users[indexPath.row]
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainProfile")
    //self.mainProfile?.user2 = user1 // Instead of this line
    vc.user2 = user1 // use this line
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: No luck :/ I set it up the table view and view controller like you suggested (see above)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open controller with that passed value, you can set that value after instantiating it

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let vc: UINavigationController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavProfile") as!  UINavigationController

// this is what your showProfileControllerForUser doing
vc.user2 =  user1

self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Would that still make it to the "mainProfile" view controller by doing it that way?

Comment: give it a try, where are you setting mainProfile?